# Swagger with custom validation

Tags: node.js, express, yaml, swagger, swagger-ui

I am using swagger and swagger ui in node js express.

What i intend to achieve is to create a custom validation that i can use in yaml directly.

eg:

```
isProgramExist() {
    if (logic here) {
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

than in yaml if i write like this, it will auto query the validation and return formatted error message. I can't find the documentation of this custom validation in yaml online.

Is this possible and how could it be done?

```
 -name: param1
  in: formData
  required: true
  type: string
  isProgramExist: true
```